# How to add automatically products (just in the backhand) to orders in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I think is necessary some custom PHP, how can be added automatically to the backhand of the order 3 products (brochure, box and leaflet) for each order?
I do not want this to be visible in the front end like using plugins like chained products but I would like simply that for each order in the backhand automatically would be added 3 specific product to this order.
The three product would be products with their own SKU code and ID of course.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the product id  you can use

```
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id,$quantity);
```

to set any product you want to customer's cart.

Comment: i do not want to add to their cart but just to the back hand of the order. so this should not be visible in the cart of the user. But just in the back hand so the shipping department also add these items to the order.